# How to calculate E[Xi Xj]?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, variance, expected-value, covariance

This question is from an example in the book of Bertsekas. (p240 of 1st edition). I would like to know why $$E[X_{i} X_{j}] = P(X_{i} = 1\text{ and }X_{j}=1)$$ and $$E[X_{i}] = P(X_{i}=1)$$. please explain to me. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_iX_j$ takes only two values $0$ and $1$. It is $1$ iff $X_i=X_j=1$. Hence $EX_iX_j$ is $1$ times the probability of $X_i=X_j=1$ plus $0$ times the probability of the complementary event.